# nothing happen when press google sign in button

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus, swift2, google-signin

i have configuered Google SDK for ios using pods.and i have added a uiview to work as Sign in button (set the class to GIDSignInButton). and added the connection. but when i press the button it wont show any thing. it does not calls the delegate methods. i search the web but nothing found. please guide me to solve this issue.

thank you

here is my viewControllar

```
class Login: UIViewController , GIDSignInUIDelegate{

@IBOutlet var googleLogIn: GIDSignInButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

    // Uncomment to automatically sign in the user.
   // GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    // TODO(developer) Configure the sign-in button look/feel
    // ...
}
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let name = user.profile.name
            let email = user.profile.email
            // ...
        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...
}
```

here is my app delegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    //Optionally add to ensure your credentials are valid:

    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self


    return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
    //FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let name = user.profile.name
            let email = user.profile.email
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                "ToggleAuthUINotification",
                object: nil,
                userInfo: ["statusText": "Signed in user:\n\(name)"])
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                "ToggleAuthUINotification", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user:GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            "ToggleAuthUINotification",
            object: nil,
            userInfo: ["statusText": "User has disconnected."])
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify once are  you added your `clientID` in your app,

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "XXXXX-XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";

return true
}
```

second

remove the line `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self` from `appdelegate` and add your view controller, try once

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
```

Comment: about Client Id; they never mentioned to include Client Id. thay must be taken it from the info.plist. but i will try this

Comment: @GishanthaJayasooriya -- try once if you not get the answer reply here, I will suppot you http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2015/03/google-sign-in-ios-100.html

Comment: i have tried giving client id. but i can not assign GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self because i used GIDSignInUIDelegate in my uiviewControllar. what can i do now

Comment: ok , check the update answer , put the break point in your **didSignInForUser**, check once

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if anyone else is facing this issue. I know it might not be in your case but for anyone else I was also facing this same issue but in my case I added Google Sign in Button in Container View which had Tap Gesture for dismissing the keyboard due to which when I tap on Google Sign-In , it didn't used to work.
Just a little stupidity from my end :)

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand your suggestion here. Are you saying we should put the GIDSignInButton inside a container view? whats the point for that ? I also have the same issue where the SFSafariViewController is not getting dismissed and it just falls back to www.google.com instead of dismissing and comming back to my app interface.

Comment: Wow, you made my day

Comment: @Shrolox glad I could help

Comment: helped This  in My case:)

Comment: Did you find a way of making the two Google prompts (for user and then allowing the scope of the app) appearing inside the container view instead of filling the entire (in my case) iPad screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tap gesture to dismiss the keyboard... add the cancelTouchesInView=false:

```
let endEditingTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleEndEditing))
endEditingTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
view.addGestureRecognizer(endEditingTap)
```